# Modifying Angular scope variables using forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following data on the server:

`people.json`:

```
{
  "Bill": "Bill the Man",
  "Jane": "Jane Doe",
  "Jack": "Jack the Ripper"
}
```

`groups.json`:

```
[
   ["Bill", "Jack"],
   ["Jane", "Jack"]
]
```

I import it in `controllers.js`:

```
var websiteApp = angular.module('websiteApp', []);

websiteApp.controller('websiteCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  // import data
  $http.get('people.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.people = data;
  });
  $http.get('groups.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.groups = data;
  });

  // fill groups with people data
  $scope.groups.forEach(function (group, i) {
    group.forEach(function (person, j) {
      $scope.groups[i][j] = $scope.people[person];
    });
  });
});
```

And then I use this with the following template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <ul><li ng-repeat="person in group">{{person}}</li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I expected to get a list of lists of names from `people.json`, but I get the first names as in `groups.json`. Some further investigation with `console.log` made it clear that the `forEach` loops are not executed. Further trials with local variables to store the data before assigning to the scope also did not succeed.

How should I approach this issue? What am I not understanding about how Angular works? (N.B.: I am new to Angular and Javascript frameworks in general.)

Comment: both of the `$http.get` calls are async.  So, there will be no data yet when the `forEach` runs.

Comment: The `foreach` is being hit before the `.success` of each `http` call due to the *async* nature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
var websiteApp = angular.module('websiteApp', []);

websiteApp.controller('websiteCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
    // import data

    getPeopleAndGroups = function() {

        var people = $http.get('people.json');
        var groups = $http.get('groups.json');

        return $q.all([people, groups]);
    }


    getPeopleAndGroups().then(function(data) {
        var people = data[0].data;
        var groups = data[1].data;

        // fill groups with people data
        groups.forEach(function(group, i) {
            group.forEach(function(person, j) {
                $scope.groups[i][j] = $scope.people[person];
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Using the `$q` library, you can return a promise, so this should help you out - I cant validate it as I'm in work, but it should get you on track.  Take a look at the [Angular q Library](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

`$http` is asynchronous in nature, you need to call the `foreach`, when both ajax requests are completed. For example:

```
var websiteApp = angular.module('websiteApp', []);

websiteApp.controller('websiteCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    // import data
    $http.get('people.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.people = data;
        $http.get('groups.json').success(function (data) {
            $scope.groups = data;
            // fill groups with people data
            $scope.groups.forEach(function (group, i) {
                group.forEach(function (person, j) {
                    $scope.groups[i][j] = $scope.people[person];
                });
            });

        });
    });



});
```